# Check which JTextField is going to get focus

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have a form with two `JTextField`s: **text1** and **text2**.

Each text field has a focus listener and I'm listening for `focusLost()` on text1 and text2.

Focus traversal is **text1 -> text2**.

When focus is lost from text2, text1 and text2 are processed, then cleared and then focus is set to text1 again.

On text2 this is my custom focus listener:

```
private class Text2FocusListener implements FocusListener{
  @Override
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0){
     if(arg0.isTemporary()){
        return;
     }
     process_input...
  }
}
```

Problem is, that if user needs to click (by mouse or keyboard) back to text1 (i.e. needs to correct data in text1 field), focus from text2 is lost and inputs from text1 and text2 are processed.

In the `if` clause I need to somehow check that focus is going to text1 and I don't know how.

Did someone else deal with similar problem?

Comment: which _if clause_ - don't see any in your snippet ;-) Or in other words: for better help sooner, show a SSCCE which demonstrates exactly what you are after and how your expectations aren't met.

Comment: darn .. was blind as to the if ;-) But still don't see any SSCCE, me being blind again?

Answer (score 2):

1. Focus/FocusSubsystem is pretty asynchrounous, you have to wrap rellated code to the `invokeLater`
2. `FocusListener` could be caused issues in the cases is added together with another listeners to the `JTextComponents`, e.g. `FocusListener` with `ItemListener` added to the (editable)`JComboBox` causing end_less loop, or with stange behavior with `Caret` together `DocumentListener` too,
3. remove these listeners on `focusLost`,
4. add only required listeners after all code inside `focusGained` ended
5. for why reasons you have needed `FocusListener`, maybe there are one two better alternatives, but nothing clear from your question, edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: ad 1: yes, processing code is in invokeLater() but this is not related to the problem.

Comment: ad 2: just this one listener is on JTextField, I know about this problem, it's not related to the problem    
ad 3: it works pretty well   
ad 5: none found, input must be validated after focus is lost on last input ("text2" field)

ad 4: hmm, if I put component just 1 pixel wide after "text2" field and it will be next component on focus traversal, than "text1" and "text2" should be processed after text2 will lost focus and if user click back to "text1" item, processing code won't process. will try, looks good..

Comment: this is academic answers to my academics points, maybe there are another ways, edit your question with SSCCE,

Comment: see my ad 4: it looks like solution?

Comment: @Ladislav DANKO by default I use another ways as FocusXxx

Answer (score 1):

`FocusEvent` has `public Component getOppositeComponent()` method

Comment: After some elaboration I'm going to answer myself: it's not possible.  In fact, I can `MyFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy` class you can implement and ask for next component through `getComponentAfter()` but this has nothing to do with question "which component will have focus in reality?".   Yes, I can ask `MyFocusTraversalPolicy` which component is after or before a component but after focus from component has been lost there isn't way to find out which componet in real will get focus (I can click by mouse on component which is out-of-order in MyFocusTraversalPolicy).